# Average length of consecutive numbers in a List<int>

Tags: dart

Given a `List<int>` where the numbers are always descending from highest to lowest and always above 0,

`List<int> numbers = [29, 22, 21, 20, 17, 16, 15, 10, 9, 8, 3, 2, 1];`

The end goal is to group up the consecutive numbers, and then look at the average length of each group.
So in this example because I see the grouping, (29), (24,23,22), (17,16,15), (10,9,8), (3,2,1), I would then expect to see

`List<int> groupedNumberLengths = [1, 3, 3, 3, 3];`

```
final double average = groupedNumberLengths.reduce((int a, int b) => a + b) / numbers.length; //2.6
return average.round() // 3
```

I was originally looping through the list and determining if the next number was more than `1` away, but I got kind of over my head inside the loop and I was wondering if anyone had a better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think about the problem you can reduce it to do the following:

```
void main() {
  final List<int> numbers = [29, 22, 21, 20, 17, 16, 15, 10, 9, 8, 3, 2, 1];
  print(avgLen(numbers)); // 3
}

int avgLen(List<int> numbers) {
  var groups = 1;

  for (var i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i - 1] - numbers[i] != 1) {
      groups++;
    }
  }

  return (numbers.length / groups).round();
}
```

The sum of all groups will always be the number of entries in your list. So we don't need to count that. So we only need to know how many groups there are.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: little bug in code, sorry

Try this:

```
int avgLen(List<int> lst) {
  final repCntLst = List<int>();
  int repCnt = 1;
  lst.reduce((prev, curr) {
    if (prev - curr == 1) {
      ++repCnt;
    } else {
      repCntLst.add(repCnt);
      repCnt = 1;
    }
    return curr;
  });
  repCntLst.add(repCnt);
  final double average =
      repCntLst.reduce((int a, int b) => a + b) / repCntLst.length; //2.6
  return average.round(); // 3
}

void main() {
  final List<int> numbers = [29, 22, 21, 20, 17, 16, 15, 10, 9, 8, 3, 2, 1];
  print(avgLen(numbers));
}
```

Comment: Oo! I forgot about using reduce in the beginning. Thank you!!

Comment: @DanMossa Please accept the answer if it solves your question, thanks.